Christiantiy Stackexchange Jubilee 2025
Probably should have asked this before Christmas, but does anybody have any ideas or desire to celebrate 2025 as a Jubilee Year.
We can't do a lot as mods in a formal way (other than commute suspensions), but we could do some works of charity that foster a sense of good will in a way we might not have done before!

Christiantiy Stackexchange Jubilee 2025
Asked
Here are a few ideas that may be plausible:

Commute some suspensions.

Offer more bonuses to certain questions.

Ask more Jubilee based questions.


